# Mounting XFS partition image from xfs_copy

Tags: mount, xfs

Used `xfs_copy` to copy a partition of the hard drive of a Fedora 27 server to a file, now trying to mount the file on my Antergos desktop I get:

```
mount: /mnt/server: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

with the command:

```
$ sudo mount -t xfs -o loop serverbackup.img /mnt/server
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

#### Idea #1

What was the command you used to create the image w/ `xfs_copy`? There are guidances for `xfs_copy` that it had to have been used on an unmounted filesystem:

> unmounted filesystem only
>
> xfs_copy should only be used to copy unmounted filesystems, read-only mounted filesystems, or frozen filesystems (see xfs_freeze(8)).  Otherwise, the generated  filesystem(s)  would  be inconsistent or corruption

#### Idea #2

Depending on your distro + version of XFS there's this bug + patch titled: [Bug 1104956 - xfs_copy will make a corrupted target when source sector is over 512](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1104956).

> ```
> Description of problem:
> 1. mkfs a xfs filesystem on some device to make its sector over 512 and
>    put some file in it
>
>    mkfs.xfs -f -s size=4096 $SCRATCH_DEV
> 2. xfs_copy $SCRATCH_DEV to $target
>
> $target is corrupted, and can't be mounted.
>
> The following patch fix it.
> ```

#### References

- [xfs_copy command examples](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/668-xfs-copy-command-examples)